# Android: If external device is attached to mobile . How can logcat be seen in Android studio

Tags: java, android, input

If external device is attached to mobile using OTG cable . How can logcat be seen in Android studio

---

I used external input reader device .

Comment: you still can see it in the window console

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Comment: thanks Jaydeep Patel